# Spring Boot: starter modules - do i need to keep them?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am starting yet another project based on spring boot.
For start it's pretty obvious and easy to go with `spring-boot-starter` dependencies. But for example I have projects which already live for 2 years and it becomes more challenging and time consuming to upgrade versions of those modules. Mostly because lot's of things auto-confugured under the hood, and there is only hidden knowledge to control them.

What would be the best practice to plan the new project for long term support and be able without any problems upgrade spring boot versions?

Are starter modules really just for start? After some time they should be fully replaced with pure modules from Spring framework?

Comment: You'll have this problem regardless of what you do. As libraries go through versions things change, if you want to stay up to date you need to read the changelog and update things. The notion of "_hidden knowledge_" you need to dismiss right away - as a developer you need to _read_ and _understand_ the autoconfiguration code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention of Spring Starter modules is not necessarily intended to be aimed at being replaced by manually defining your dependencies.  In fact, it's more the opposite, as the set of dependencies defined in starters are tested to work as expected as it provides an opinionated set.

The pattern laid out by Spring Boot is two fold, autoconfigure modules and starter modules:

- Autoconfigure modules that generally do not, unless necessary, require dependencies downstream.  Autoconfigure modules will compile against one or many modules, and then enable configurations within your application context based on rules generally governed by what libraries and components are available at context initialization.  This is useful as it provides reasonable baseline configurations that can be used in a variety of scenarios, without enforcing what particular libraries/vendors downstream consumers must use.  However, because they are intended to be used in a variety of scenarios, it is incumbent upon you as the consumer to ensure you have a valid context.
- Starter modules are complimentary to autoconfigure modules.  They provide an opinionated set of dependencies downstream, along with autoconfigure dependencies, to allow consumers to get started.  Generally, but not necessarily, starter modules themselves are fairly empty and often do not contain any classes, as their main purpose is to just provide a POM that can be used for transitive dependencies.

Although your query is not about developing custom auto-configuration, the Spring Boot documentation regarding [developing your own auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) does a good job explaining the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally when we develop a Spring application, we need to include all the required dependencies (spring or other framework jar) by ourself. Starter is intended to minimize such configuration . It does not have any codes or logic inside . You can think that it is just a configuration setting which pre-defines some dependencies. Including a starter will automatically include all of the dependencies defined by this starter to your project thanks to the build system (e.g Maven) 's "transitive dependencies" features.

So you can see that starter provides one of the SpringBoot philosophy, which enable developer to create a Spring app that can "just run" quickly without much configuration ,  it definitely will not be replaced by the Spring.

Comment: @Boris the Spider  Really? What you mention is not provided by starter. It is included in something like the `spring-boot-autoconfigure` which will be included by `spring-boot-starter` . This is  what I see from the code (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter).

Comment: And I double check that all the starter only contain "pom.xml" without any codes. (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters). So please consider one more time if you down vote my answer because of that reason

Comment: Edit for what? At least you have to let me know why you think my answer deserve your downvote such that I can edit for you

Comment: Oh i see . Done . I don't know  it has such rule.Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I basically know how it works, but then it's just feels wrong that they decided to call those modules 'starter'. Naming - I think that's my problem here :)